# Limit using Itô isometry

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

I have a silly problem I don't understand. if $\chi$ denotes, the characteristic function and $B_s$ a Browninan motion, I need to show $\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}dB_s\to 0$ in $L^2(P)$ as $\epsilon\searrow0$. However, using Itô's identity I obtain $$E\left[\left(\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}dB_s\right)^2\right]=E\left[\int_0^t \left(\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\right)^2\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}ds\right]\le\int_0^tds=t\not\to0$$

Comment: Is the limit being taken as $\epsilon \to 0^+$?

Comment: Sorry, what you've written doesn't seem to be clear to me. Can you show how you've used Itô's isometry here?

Comment: sorry there was a typo

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear. I'm not sure what you are squaring in the first expression, why it goes to zero, what you are integrating against after the first equality, or why the latter expectation equals $\int_0^t ds$. Can you rephrase?

Comment: It's clear now. Perhaps your inequality is a bit wasteful? $E(B_s^2 \chi_{B_s \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)})$ can be computed in terms of $\epsilon$. That may help.

Comment: I am not sure how though. The only thing I see is $B_s^2\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}\le \epsilon^2$ but then this cancel with the $\epsilon^2$ in the denominator

Comment: As a supplementary to Jose's comment, note that $$\mathbf{E}\bigl[B_s^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}}\bigr]=\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}x^2 f_{B_s}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: @SangchulLee, thank you. I have $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}x^2f_{B_s}(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}x^2e^{-x^2/2s}dx$ but then it seems this integral is a bit a mess which involves the $erf(\cdot)$ function no?

Comment: That is exactly why I provided an upper bound. :)

Comment: Oh, it seems I am blind... Thank you, everything is clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint by @SangchulLee we can prove the required limit:

$$\begin{align*}
E\left[\left(\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}dB_s\right)^2\right] & = E\left[\int_0^t \left(\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\right)^2\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}ds\right] & \text{(Itô isometry)} \\
&= \int_0^t \epsilon^{-2} E\left[B_s^2\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)  } \right] ds & \text{(Tonelli's theorem)} \\
&\leq \int_0^t \epsilon^{-2} \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2 \pi s}}dx ds \\
&= \int_0^t \epsilon^{-2} \frac{2}{3\sqrt{2 \pi s}} \epsilon^3  ds \\
&= \epsilon \cdot C \sqrt{t} & \text{(for some constant }C)\\
&\to 0 & \text{(as } \epsilon \to 0^+ )
\end{align*}$$

This implies that $\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{\epsilon}\chi_{B_s\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}dB_s \to 0$ in $L^2(P)$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, as desired.